# How can i use substring or other function to divide a string into words?

Tags: java, string, swing, jpanel

So I have this function:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String input = jt.toString();
}
```

And I want to use substring or any other function to divide the words in this sentence.

Like using substring from 0 until it finds a "space" and then it should stop and then start again until the end of the sentence.

Comment: What was the 'something' that you tried? Might be helpful...

Comment: Start looking into `String#split(String)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to use the Split method for the String class.

```
String[] input = jt.toString().split("\\s+");
```

This method will give you an array where each cell of the array will contain a word.

`jt` stands for `JText`?

If yes, you should get the text from the component instead of converting the object to string using the following instruction: `jt.getText()`

Answer (score 0):

`string[] words = input.Split(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with stringbuilder if you care about saving memory.

```
public class splitword {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  String input = "Hi! Can you please split me into pieces :0";
  String[] toSplit = new StringBuilder(input).toString().split("[\\s\\p{P}&& [^']]+");

    for (String x : toSplit) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    }
    }
```